# Remove server header from Application Gateway V2

Tags: azure-application-gateway

We were asked to remove the server header from the http response which gives details of Application gateway v2 for the GET/POST request against the URL.
I have added the rewrites rule to remove the server header in APP GW v2. For few GET/POST requests, it wont show the server headers but when we try GET request with url http://xx.com/../../../cbs?_v=15.0.36510.0&aid=test HTTP/1.1, the server header still shows up.

Any condition do we need to apply for the rewrites to remove server header.

Comment: This has just come up in a pen test that I am working on.  Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: This is still not supported by the product itself

[Some Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/627494/app-gateway-v2-unable-to-remove-server-response-he.html)

> Rewrites do not work on responses generated directly from the Application Gateway.
> This is currently not supported and is part of the backlog. There isn’t an ETA on this but we will be working on this limitation soon.
> You can find it in [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#limitations)